# append option tag with value which are selected in different select tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have Three Select Tags
Two with player names

```
<select >
<option value="plarer1">plarer1</option>
<option value="plarer2">plarer2</option>
</select>
<select >
<option value="plarer3">plarer3</option>
<option value="plarer4">plarer4</option>
</select>
```

and the third one is empty and hidden
when I will select the value from both select tags they may both appear with value and name in the third select tag

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?  Unless you require some server-side logic or interactions then I imagine you'd do this entirely in JavaScript.

Comment: ok. So what's your question? You haven't described a problem or any kind of difficulty. Nor is there any code which we can help you to fix. This is not a site where you just post your vague requirement and people rush to write code for you, for free. You're expected to show some research and/or coding effort first, and then explain where you're stuck in relation to achieving your goal. If you have no clue where to start, then do some research...it's too early a stage for a question here.

Comment: Here's a clue though...use JavaScript and handle the "change" events on both the visible selects. When the change occurs, check the values in each select, and then use that information to decide whether to show/hide the third select, or whether to do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is using javascript in the browser:

First make function to create a simple HTML `select` element that contains a number of options specified by their title. This is pretty straight forward:

```
function createDropdownWithTitles(...optionTitles) {
  const dropdown = document.createElement('select')
  const defaultOption = new Option('Choose', null, true, true)
  defaultOption.disabled = true
  dropdown.add(defaultOption)
  for (const title of optionTitles) {
    const option = new Option(title, title)
    dropdown.add(option)
  }
  return dropdown
}
```

Then make a function that creates a dynamic dropdown. This is an HTML `select` element that will dynamically retrieve its options from the selected options of other dropdown boxes.

This becomes a bit more complex. There are two things we need to do:

- Keep track of the dropdowns that are filled in already: we call this `filledInDropdowns` in our code. Once all these dropdowns are filled in we can make the dynamic dropdown visible.
- Keep track of the contents of newly filled in dropdowns. We should reflect these contents in our dynamic dropdown.

Here is it in code

```
function createDropdownBasedOn(...otherDropdowns) {
  const dropdown = document.createElement('select')
  dropdown.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  const filledInDropdowns = new Array(otherDropdowns.length)
  for (const [index, dropdown] of otherDropdowns.entries()) {
    dropdown.addEventListener('change', event => fillIn(event.currentTarget, index))
    filledInDropdowns[index] = false
  }
  function fillIn(dependency, index) {
    filledInDropdowns[index] = true
    dropdown[index] = new Option(dependency.value, dependency.value)
    for (const filledIn of filledInDropdowns) {
      if (filledIn === false) return
    }
    dropdown.style.visibility = 'visible'
  }
  return dropdown
}
```

And then to wrap up create some sample dropdowns:

```
const dropdownA = createDropdownWithTitles('Player 1', 'Player 2')
const dropdownB = createDropdownWithTitles('Player 3', 'Player 4')

document.body.appendChild(dropdownA)
document.body.appendChild(dropdownB)
document.body.appendChild(createDropdownBasedOn(dropdownA, dropdownB))
```

Check out a working example:

```js
function createDropdownWithTitles(...optionTitles) {
  const dropdown = document.createElement('select')
  const defaultOption = new Option('Choose', null, true, true)
  defaultOption.disabled = true
  dropdown.add(defaultOption)
  for (const title of optionTitles) {
    const option = new Option(title, title)
    dropdown.add(option)
  }
  return dropdown
}

function createDropdownBasedOn(...otherDropdowns) {
  const dropdown = document.createElement('select')
  dropdown.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  const filledInDropdowns = new Array(otherDropdowns.length)
  for (const [index, dropdown] of otherDropdowns.entries()) {
    dropdown.addEventListener('change', event => fillIn(event.currentTarget, index))
    filledInDropdowns[index] = false
  }
  function fillIn(dependency, index) {
    filledInDropdowns[index] = true
    dropdown[index] = new Option(dependency.value, dependency.value)
    for (const filledIn of filledInDropdowns) {
      if (filledIn === false) return
    }
    dropdown.style.visibility = 'visible'
  }
  return dropdown
}

const dropdownA = createDropdownWithTitles('Player 1', 'Player 2')
const dropdownB = createDropdownWithTitles('Player 3', 'Player 4')

document.body.appendChild(dropdownA)
document.body.appendChild(dropdownB)
document.body.appendChild(createDropdownBasedOn(dropdownA, dropdownB))
```